# ReactJS: how to output variable containing HTML?

Tags: reactjs

I'm ReactJS noob, so I am having this terrible problem:
got variable named adminLink containing the following:

```
<span class="link" onclick="showLogin">Login</span>
```

I need to print it out, as HTML.
If I do following

```
<div className="adminLink">
    {adminLink}
</div>
```

I get the text, not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hello you would simply need to do this:

```
myComp = React.createClass({
  render:function(){
    adminLink = [];

    adminLink.push(<span className="link" onclick="showLogin">Login</span>);

    render (<div className="adminLink">
              {adminLink}
            </div> )
  }
});
```

Try it. hope it helped.

EDIT:

please notice the "class" needs to be changed to className.
Also: using an array is not neccessary, I just like to do it in case I have to attach other JSX later on

Comment: also onclick needs to be onClick, and you need to pass a function to it (a string is not a function)

Comment: Also you dont need to push it to an array. You could also just add it to a variable like this ```var adminLink = (<span className="link" onclick="showLogin">Login</span>);```

Comment: @magnudae just as I mentioned in my EDIT :) Its just my style of adding JSX and optionally pushing more in some later point

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `dangerouslySetInnerHtml`:

```
<div className="adminLink" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: adminLink}}>
    {adminLink}
</div>
```

It is well explained on the [JSX wiki page about HTML entities](http://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-gotchas.html#html-entities) why this is dangerous and what other choices you have.